# Getting the date in YYYYMMDD format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm looking for the best way to return a date in a **`YYYYMMDD`** format, such as **`20180106`**.

Here is how I do it:

```
var x = new Date();
var y = x.getFullYear().toString();
var m = (x.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var d = x.getDate().toString();
(d.length == 1) && (d = '0' + d);
(m.length == 1) && (m = '0' + m);
var yyyymmdd = y + m + d;
alert(yyyymmdd);
```

Is it correct enough or can I achieve the same in a better way?

Comment: To avoid those magic constants, you could also do `const components = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDay()]; const paddings = [4, 2, 2]; components.map((component, i) => component.toString().padStart(paddings[i], '0')).join('');`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: What do the fifth and sixth lines do? I'm learning JavaScript and I get the left part is a Boolean check but you're using "and" with code that sets a variable?

Comment: @BruceWayne if the boolean check is true, the right side statement will get executed (which here sets the variable), otherwise; if the left condition fails, it'll not execute.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Oh, woah that's pretty neat! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code looks good and works well. Since it provides a useful bit of work, you should convert it into a function. Then you can copy that function to another program if you need so.

```
function yyyymmdd() {
    var x = new Date();
    var y = x.getFullYear().toString();
    var m = (x.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    var d = x.getDate().toString();
    (d.length == 1) && (d = '0' + d);
    (m.length == 1) && (m = '0' + m);
    var yyyymmdd = y + m + d;
    return yyyymmdd;
}
```

To make this code a little easier to read, you should rename `x` to `now`.

You could also omit the calls to `toString()`, which makes the code a little shorter. Plus, you should introduce the variables `mm` and `dd`, so that you don't reassign to the `d` and `m` variables. This is a generally useful pattern, because when stepping through the code you can always look at the variable definition to see how it was computed. This is not possible for variables that change their value during execution.

The modified code looks like this:

```
function yyyymmdd() {
    var now = new Date();
    var y = now.getFullYear();
    var m = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = now.getDate();
    var mm = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    var dd = d < 10 ? '0' + d : d;
    return '' + y + mm + dd;
}
```

Or, you could inline the last few lines:

```
function yyyymmdd() {
    var now = new Date();
    var y = now.getFullYear();
    var m = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = now.getDate();
    return '' + y + (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d;
}
```

That last variant is harder to read though, therefore I prefer the previous one.

Another possibility is to define a helper function that produces a two-digit string:

```
function yyyymmdd() {
    function twoDigit(n) { return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n; }

    var now = new Date();
    return '' + now.getFullYear() + twoDigit(now.getMonth() + 1) + twoDigit(now.getDate());
}
```

Comment: There is also [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). `m.padStart(2, '0')`

Answer (score 3):

For getting the `0` padded date and month values, I generally follow this approach:

```
let d = ('0' + x.getDate()).substring(-2)
```

However, the `Date` objects have a [`.toISOString`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/toisostring) method, which returns the string in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` format, which you can split on `T` and then replace `-` (or vice-versa):

```
formatted_date = (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/-/g, '').split('T')[0]
  // same as     (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/-/g, '')
```

Comment: Woops... This first chosen solution has just failed. 
A new Date() like `Sun Jan 07 2018 00:26:00 GMT+0100` toISOString() gives `2018-01-06T23:26:00.445Z` resulting in `20180106` instead of the expected `20180107`

Comment: `toISOString` always uses UTC time, and I have no idea why the API doesn't include a function like `toLocalISOString`, which would be quite useful.